# About Pointer Scanning

Tags: reverse-engineering, reverse

At the moment I am trying to find pointers myself in a Game without using any kind of additional software. I've been programming my own software but I couldn't come with a way of replicating, or finding a way of implementing Pointer Scanning or even a way to find pointers...

Can someone explain to me how it works, maybe even im missing fundamentals.

Extra question: Isn't pointers are just integers? That points to someother memory address? Can't we just read them by ReadProcessMemory winapi function?

Extra Question2: In cheat engine what does Green addresses mean when you search a value? (I think they are static? or pointers?) And how do cheat engine determine it?

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a variable which can contain a memory address, and it can be represented by an integer yes.

Pointer Scanner in Cheat Engine brute forces all pointer paths with the parameters you give it.

You give it an address to scan for, it scans for this address to find all pointers to it.  It then subtracts a number like 0x1000 and then scans each one of those addresses in that range for pointers which point to those addresses.  In this way it will find all 1 level pointer with an offset between 0 and 0x1000.  Then it goes through this new list and does the same thing, going one level deeper.  It keeps doing this until it either finds a static address or an address that is relative to a module's base address and it can't go any deeper.

The pointer "chains" as I like to call them are then listed in the pointer database.

Before you try to understand pointers in the context of reverse engineering you should become an adequate programmer, in this way your understanding of how pointers work moving forwards can be applied to your understanding of them going in the opposite direction, which is the process of reversing them.